# Multiple jQuery ajax calls; how can associate callbacks to requests?

Tags: jquery

If you are dynamically creating ajax requests, since they come to execute the success callback asychronously, how can you know what request is being responded by each callback ?

Example:

I have an array of n Questions, and a server gives back the Answers:

```
var questions = Array("What's your name?", "What's your mom's name?", "What's your pet's name?");
for (var i=0; i<questions.length; i++) {
            $.get ("server.php", { "Question" : questions[i] },
                    function(data) { 
                        /* I want to process answer, but at this time I cannot access the value of i,
                           so what's question is being answered ? */
                    }, "json");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the next:

```
$.get("server.php", { "Question" : questions[i] },
    function(data) {
        alert("success. The next question is being answered: "+questions[i]);
    }, "json")
    .done(function() { alert("second succes. This question has been answered:" + questions[i]); })
    .fail(function() { alert("Error answering this question: "  +questions[i]); })
```

You can send in the response what question is being answered too, so you have that information in the data variable.

**Working test**:

```
var questions = Array("What's your name?", "What's your mom's name?", "What's your pet's name?");
for (var i=0; i<questions.length; i++) {
   sendGet(questions[i]);
}

function sendGet(question) {
    $.get("server.php", { "Question" : question },
    function(data) {
        alert("success. The next question is being answered: "+question);
    }, "json")
    .done(function() { alert("second succes. This question has been answered:" + question); })
    .fail(function() { alert("Error answering this question: "  +question); })
}
```

Comment: the .done and .fail callbacks suffer the same problem as success: at the time they are executed, the value of i has changed, so this solution doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortuntely I cannot change the behavior of the server, so I cannot make it sending me back the question.

Comment: @Flatline1963 I eddited the post adding another posibility, check if that works :)

Comment: Great! It works. Wrapping the ajax call into a new function's scope did the trick. Many thanks